# Admin-on-REST: How can a label become 2 lines?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there an (easy) way to split the `label` in 2 lines? Or that would require a custom component?

```
<TextField label="This is a very long text label for the datagrid column" source="receptionProtocol" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert but this doesn't appear to be possible without a custom label or component, because `label` itself is always passed as a string into [FieldTitle](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/49a616c93d1ee5ea0bfa3c5f7abea0bb29c8d01c/src/util/FieldTitle.js), with any angle brackets encoded.